# converting python dict to protobuf

Tags: python, dictionary, protocol-buffers

How can I convert the following dict to protobuf ?
I have to send a protobuf as a payload to an mqtt broker.
I'm using python 3.8

```
publish_msg = {
        "token":"xxxxxxxx",
        "parms":{
            "fPort":8,
            "data":b"MDQzYzAwMDE=",
            "confirmed":False,
            "devEUI":"8CF9572000023509"
        }
    }
```

My protobuf is defined as follows:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package publish;


message DLParams{
    string DevEUI = 1;
    int32 FPort = 2;
    bytes Data = 3;
    bool Confirm = 4;
}

message DeviceDownlink {
    string Token = 1;
    DLParams Params = 2;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can add some example python code of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I had solved the problem. I wanted to send messages in the form of protobuf. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```py
import json
from google.protobuf import json_format

# Create an empty message
dl = DeviceDownlink_pb2.DeviceDownlink()

# Get the json string for your dict
json_string = json.dumps(publish_msg)

# Put the json contents into your message
json_format.Parse(json_string, dl)
```

Comment: This crashes if the proto has any fields of type `google.protobuf.Timestamp` and the dictionary has them as a sub-dict like `"my_timestamp_field": {"seconds": 1234567, "nanos": 1234567}`. Any thoughts on how to handle these in this approach?

Comment: I can only guess what your error mesage is, but make sure the dictionary keys match _exactly_ the definition of the protobuf message. You could try constructing your message maually and printing it out to see the exact field names. Or examine the .proto file.

Comment: Is this  stable?

Comment: I can't comment on the stability from a software maintainer's point of view, however it is maintained by google who usually has good software quality. From a user's perspective, I have encountered no stability issues.

Comment: You can skip the intermediate conversion to a JSON string and use `json_format.ParseDict(publish_msg, dl)`.